# The navigation props is missing - react-navigation V3.0

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Why I'm still receiving the following:

```
"The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly."
```

Here is my **code**:

```jsx
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    About: {
      screen: Header2,
    },
  },
  DrawerConfig
);


const MyApp11 = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);


export default class App12 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <MyApp11 />;
  }
}
```

Working with react native and react navigation.

---

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animated-hamburger": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Add some more details about your issue with code

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are exporting navigation in the wrong way. you should not wrap navigation constant to react component, just export it directly from your js file.

create a route.js file and add your navigation wrapper.

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    About: {
      screen: Header2,
    },
  },
  DrawerConfig
);


const MyApp11 = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
export default MyApp11
```

Now in app.js import it and pass to the component

app.js

```
import Routes from 'path_to_route_file';
export default class App extends Component{
   render(){
    return(
      <View>
         <Routes />
      </View>
    )
```

Comment: I have already try to write it only with " export default MyApp11" (like in your answer), but it send the same issue.